# URL disapears in createview when going from get to POST

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

I have a question regarding an issue where I'm out of options and best describes with what is seen in the log.

Some background :

`/order/createnumber/` is just a CBV createView that will show a create form.

the url looks like

```
    url(r"^createnumber/$", views.OrderCreate.as_view(), name="order-create"),
```

The Class looks like

```
class OrderCreate(CreateView):
    """ CBV for creating order"""
    model = Order
    form_class = OrderFormCreate
```

The above is working for a GET request put fails for a POST request, where both URLs are the same.

```
web_1     |- - [17/Dec/2021:13:08:04 +0100] "GET /order/createnumber/ HTTP/1.0" 200 10209 "http://mytestsite.local/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:95.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/95.0"
web_1     | Not Found: /order/createnumber/
```

- It happens in my QA environment only, I'm  using gunicorn.
- In development it is working as expected, there I use the django runserver

Any ideas on this ?

Answer (score 0):

I used get_object_or_404, the trapped an error.